# How to navigate to each link on web page using protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

[Html code for this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJVim.png)I have collected the count of all the links (using 'then' without each) that I want but when I try to click on each of them I'm getting "Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". Here is my code:

```
verifylinks() {
    var alllinks = element(by.css('div.unity'))
    var links = alllinks.all(by.tagname("a"));

    number.each(function (items){
        items.click();

        //I will be validating something here

        browser.navigate().back;
    }
}
```

This worked for some other people on stack overflow but I tried to do same thing and its throwing the error. Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: what is `number` in you method in question>

Comment: Sorry it is "links"

Comment: ok. Could you share the `html` of your page and the error?

Comment: I have given link to my html code and the error is " Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 1, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, div.community a)"

Comment: try the locator `links=element.all(by.css('div>h3>a'));`. With the error it is clear that the problem is with the locator

Comment: Thank you so much Madan finally it worked when I changed the locator.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on link enter another page, even you navigate back, but Selenium will treat the return page is an new page which is not the same page where you find all links.

Therefor, when click on the next link found from the old page on the new page, Selenium detects the link is not from the new page and throws `stale element reference` exception.

To resolve the issue, you need to **find the link again on the new page**.

```
verifylinks() {

  var alllinks = element.all(by.css('div.unity a'));

  browser.sleep(15000); // just for debug purpose to wait page loading.

  alllinks.count().then(function(length) {

    console.log('link amount: ' + length);

    for(let i=0;i<length;i++) {

      alllinks.get(i).click();
      // validate something here

      browser.navigate().back();

      browser.sleep(5000); 
      // sleep for short time to wait page load for debug purpose,
      // recommend change to browser.wait()
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks yong I tried your answer and getting different error now as "- Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 1, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, div.community a).... can you help with this yong please...when i checked the count it showed 131 but not sure why I'm getting this

Comment: Try this css locator `div.unity a` manually in browser's DevTool to see it can find how many links. And I add a sleep after navigate back to wait page load.

Comment: I see 131 links under that yong but I still get the above error (index out of bound)even after adding sleep

Comment: I add sleep 15 seconds to wait page load before find all links, in case you not wait before invoke this function.  Please try again.

Comment: And please confirm which locator is right? `div.community a` is from your error log, `div.unity a` is from your given code.

Comment: I used the entire code that you posted and the correct locator is 'community' and I'm still getting count as 131 and its clicking on first link and throwing same error."- Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 1, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, div.community a)"

Comment: `browser.navigate().back;` should be `browser.navigate().back();`. Have you not notice the page not return back after the first click during your running.  it's such a obvious phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks @yong it works fine now with your code and with updated locator(suggested by madhan) Thank you so much for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

`links=element.all(by.css('div>h3>a'));`

With the error it is clear that the problem is with the locator

Comment: It will be great if you could mark the answer correct so that will help others who face the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Yes I tried it but its not allowing me to do so "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."